# Is Visual C++ SEH available on other OS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cross-platform, seh, structured-exception

I learned about Visual C++ Structured Exception Handling (SEH) recently. I am considering implementing it, but my code is supposed to be as cross platform as possible. In the future, I'm thinking of porting ny code to Linux, MAC, Android, IOS and potentially consoles. Is SEH something that can work on all of these platforms?!

Comment: No, is the simple answer.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782915/what-should-i-know-about-structured-exceptions-seh-in-c) might be interesting

Comment: Sadly not.  The magic that is `SEH` is Windows-only, nothing else comes close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SEH is a Microsoft-specific extension. Clang-cl has partial support for SEH (on Windows platforms), which could presumably be adapted for use on other OSes, but it wouldn’t be straightforward and it wouldn’t offer support for the sorts of things you can catch with SEH but not standard C++ extensions. Don’t use SEH if you want to write platform-independent code.

Comment: Needs kernel support, I'm pretty certain.

Comment: What needs kernel support?